# How to search the web for punctuation or symbols

Tags: search-engines

I'm trying to search the web for `"!= null &&"` for research reasons. Is there any search engine that will correctly search such an unusual query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that that's a piece of code, there's [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch).